# Are there any "fake" Italian words used in English?

Tags: slang, italian

Now that we've furnished so many interesting words and ideas in response to @Adrian's request regarding pseudo-Gallicisms, why not do pseudo-Italian pseudo-loanwords in English? To paraphrase Adrian:

> By pseudo-Italian I mean words that are of Italian origin but are not actually correct.  I mean Italian-derived terms that have evolved to the point of no longer being common-usage Italian.

For instance:

***Gumare***: : a longtime mistress; from the Italian *comare*, which means "second mother" or "godmother".

Comment: Hmm.  Methinks someone's trying to ride the coattails of the "fake French" question.  Judging from the downvotes, maybe what everyone's sayin' is, "Fuggettaboutit."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Both questions received 2 close-votes. But it's not fair in terms of upvotes.

Comment: Not an accepted part of normal English, but the Canadian lingerie store "La Senza" directly translates to "the without" in Italian.

Comment: Basically you just swallow the leading "th" sound and append a trailing "uh" to many words --  "at's a spicy meatuh balluh".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[*False Italianisms in British and American English: A Meta-Lexicographic Analysis* by Cristiano Furiassi](http://www.euralex.org/elx_proceedings/Euralex2012/pp771-777%20Furiassi.pdf) has a list of selected false Italianisms. Lest there be any doubt about what it’s meant by false Italianisms, here it is in the autor’s own words:

> False Italianisms – which most English speakers believe to be purely Italian – are created when genuine lexical borrowings from Italian are so reinterpreted by a recipient language, English in this case, that native speakers of Italian would not recognize them as part of their own lexical inventory and would neither understand nor use.

And here is a selection of the selection. Opening the list we have:

> [*Alfresco*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alfresco)

In English it means in the open air. To express the same idea in Italian you’d say [*all’aperto*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/aperto) (in the open). [*Fresco*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/fresco) is Italian for *fresh* (of fruit), *recent* (news), *pleasantly cool*, etc.

> [*Confetti*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confetti)

Now in Italain [*confetti*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/confetto) (singular, *confetto*) are sugar-coated almonds, pistachios, etc; or pills. The little, brightly coloured papers are [*coriandoli*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/coriandoli) (plural of *coriandolo*, also *coriander*).

> [*Inferno*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inferno)

This in Italian for [*hell*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/inferno). A large fire in Italian would be [*incendio*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/incendio).

> [*Latte*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latte)

is Italian for [*milk*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/latte). If you want a mixture of coffee and milk in Italy ask for a *[latte macchiato](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/macchiato)* (stained milk) or a *caffellatte*.

> [*Pepperoni* or *peperoni*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pepperoni)

Ask for *peperoni* (singular, [*peperone*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/peperone)) in Italy and you’ll get *peppers*. If it is the spicy sausage you want ask for *salame [piccante](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/piccante)* instead.

Comment: Could you please name the paper, and add a few more fake Italinisms to your answer. The list is 100% accurate, my pet hate is *latte*, which does not mean "white/milky coffee" in Italian. *Confetti* is another good one, the Italian for torn pieces of colored paper  is "coriandoli".

Comment: @Mari-LouA, will do. Just let me have my morning latte first :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, see how you like it now.

Comment: I mean… a fair few of these aren't _really_ false Italianisms as such, just extended meanings and shortenings that took place in English after the words were borrowed. _Inferno_ still primarily means ‘hell’;  a _latte_ is still a _caffe latte_ that's just been shortened; and _peperoni_ is still primarily (well, to some at least) a sausage with peppers in it that's just been shortened.

Comment: Note that *al fresco* also means *in jail*. *Mandare al fresco* can mean "send someone in a cool place", but more frequently means to send them to jail (also, it's two words - *alfresco* doesn't exist in Italian. The closest word is perhaps *affresco* (or *a fresco*) which is a painting technique).

Comment: @LSerni That is very interesting: an English speaker being told in Italy they were being taken to an al fresco dinner would be in for a surprise.

Comment: There is actually *exactly* that in Volterra. I believe once they were called *cene al fresco* (al fresco dinners) and it meant *both* a cool place and a prison, as the "restaurant" was actually the Volterra Penitentiary Facility. Now they are called *Cene Galeotte* (http://www.cenegaleotte.it/info/), and it's another pun - *galeotto* means a romantic matchmaker (from Galahad), but it's also a convict (from *galea*: a galley oar-slave).

Answer (score 3):

A very nice fake Italianism is in use especially I think in Southern California, where I write from. It's dated, I think, no longer as common as a decade ago. But it's to say that you and someone else are "simpatico," meaning you get along famously. One of the reasons I especially like this one is it has a twin Italian usage that is a false Anglicism: "Noi due abbiamo un buon feeling." That's a very odd use of feeling. Of course, the correct use of simpatico would be to say that a person is simpatico, not to say that she and I are simpatico, meaning well assorted or that we get along.

Comment: Erm, it is also possibly from Spanish, which seems more likely given how close CA is to Mexico...

Comment: It has been used in English for a long time - at least throughout the 20th century and probably back to whenever English speakers and Italian speakers mixed.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simpatico) has a nice discussion of the word's history. It says it was borrrowed into English from Italian and Spanish, at first, 1864 onwards, with the meaning it has in those languages ("likeable'), but "in recent years, however, the word's meaning has shifted."

Comment: Simpatico(a) in Italian means good looking. She is simpatica or he is simpatico is how that word would be used. It sounds very strange for someone to use it the way you describe. I